# Appending to array of dicts only puts last record

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I have the following problem. I'm assembling an array of dict. However, the append command is putting only the last record. Note that for increments the variable `i` and cycles through the list.

The GITHUB API request returns 100 records in the `items` list, so I go through this list taking only the information I'm interested in and form a dict for each record and add that record to the list.

The `print()` command at the end of the code shows an array with *all* data equal to the last data in the items array.

```
import requests
import json

def requisicao_api(url):
    resposta = requests.get(url)
    if resposta.status_code == 200:
        return resposta.json()
    else:
        return resposta.status_code

def imprime_repositorios(self):
    dados_api = self.requisicao_api()
    if type(dados_api) is not int:
        for i in range(len(dados_api)):
            print(dados_api[i]['name'])
    else:
        print(dados_api)

urlprincipal = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:data-science&sort=stars&order=desc&page=1&per_page=100'
dados_api = requisicao_api(urlprincipal)

items = dados_api['items']

def criar_json(nome):
    with open(nome, 'w') as f:
        return f

lista_registros = []

registro = {}

for i in range(len(items)):
    registro[ 'nome' ]    = items[i]['full_name']
    registro[ 'estrelas'] = items[i]['stargazers_count']
    lista_registros.append(registro)

print(lista_registros)
```

Result:

```
[{'nome': 'gopherdata/gophernotes', 'estrelas': 2917},
 {'nome': 'gopherdata/gophernotes', 'estrelas': 2917},
 {'nome': 'gopherdata/gophernotes', 'estrelas': 2917},
   ...  100 total
 {'nome': 'gopherdata/gophernotes', 'estrelas': 2917},
 {'nome': 'gopherdata/gophernotes', 'estrelas': 2917}]
```

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
This code is not minimal.  You say that your problem is simply appending to one list from another, but your code clutters this with JSON, an HTTP request, and other irrelevant overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the dictionary creation inside the loop like this because since you append the variable itself to the list as soon as you change the values of the keys it will update for all copies of that dictionary because it points to the same dictionary so all those values in the list will just take the values of the last values you pass to each of the dictionary's keys

```py
for i in range(len(items)):
    registro = {}
    registro[ 'nome' ]    = items[i]['full_name']
    registro[ 'estrelas'] = items[i]['stargazers_count']
    lista_registros.append(registro)
```